# Break dojo tabs onto multiple rows?

Tags: rows, dojo, tabcontainer

Is is possible to have a dijit TabContainer with tabs on more that one row instead of the default situation (where you scroll left and right to see the extra tabs)? I'm using dojo 1.8 and the claro theme.

Comment: Also is the use of **data-dojo-props** documented anywhere? I can't find it. I managed to find tabPosition on another website but between its lack of popularity (compared to other frameworks) and its documentation (which I find lacking) dojo is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that adding controllerWidget="dijit.layout.TabController" will break the tabs onto multiple rows:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" controllerWidget="dijit.layout.TabController" doLayout="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

http://shaneosullivan.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/dojo-tabcontainer-beating-the-wrap/

Apparently it's called "wrapping tabs".

I think you can put almost anything in the data-dojo-props that you can inject in the contructor of the widget, when you use dojo programmatically. To find out what you can use in there consult the dojo api & take a look at the properties of a widget:

https://dojotoolkit.org/api/

Here is a link to how the dojo parser (= the thing that transforms your declarative code to actual javascript) handles stuff:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html

Comment: This actually does the opposite of what I want to do. I guess in the example on that web page where they are using an older version of dojo, wrapping was an issue. Now I _want_ my tabs to wrap (using dojo 1.7) but can't quite figure it out.